# Transit in Schengen area

Tags: schengen, transit, international-travel, egyptian-citizens

I am going to Serbia which is non-schengen country and I have a transit in Austria which is a schengen country and I have a valid single entry visa which I don't want to use now. So my passport is going to be stamped while I am in the transit?

Comment: Where are you flying from, and is Austria your only transit point, or do you have multiple stops?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133452/where-do-you-go-through-passport-control-when-transiting-through-another-schenge

Comment: What is your full itinerary and are the flights on a single for ticket or booked separately? Also, what is your citizenship (nationality)?

Comment: I am Egyptian. My itinerary is not single. And Asutria is the only transit.

Comment: What does "my itinerary is not single" mean?  Do you have separate tickets for your flight to Vienna and your flight from Vienna to Serbia?

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a single ticket, with transit in Austria, you won't have to go through passport control, as you will just remain airside. You won't be using that single entry visa.

If you have two separate tickets, it might be difficult to do that, as your luggage won't be checked through and you have to go outside and recheck the bag, utilizing your visa.

Comment: In a comment, OP says "my itinerary is not single."  It's possible that this means "my itinerary is not booked on a single ticket," and all the more likely that it means this because it was a response to the question "are the flights on a single for ticket or booked separately?" (sic).  If that is the case, then there could well be a problem.